# What damage can someone do with a logged play store account?

Tags: applications, google-play-store

Let's say I have 500 tablets that I'm using for educational purposes at a highschool. In order to preload the app and receive automatic updates later, we have a single dummy Google Account that's logged into Google Play Store. The question is, once we give these tablets out to our students, some of whom we should assume are tech savvy and up to do no good, what damage can they do with the fact that all devices share the same account?

Now, if the damage they can do only applies to their device, we're ok with that. For instance, of course they can log out and in with a different account, which is ok. And of course they could use and abuse the tablet as they could any other tablet. That's ok too.

What we don't want to happen is for one user to be able to impact another user because of that shared account. Since they're all logged into the same account, can they access the email of that account? Could they force other tablets of the same account to download other apps? Could they force other apps to log out? What's the worst that could happen?

Comment: you can protect play store with app lock or some similar apps for safety...

Comment: I think as long as the 'dummy' account's password remains secret you're fine. I would worry about the 'dummy' account being hit by spam. If you want more controls I'll assume you've looked into [Android Enterprise Mobile Management software](https://developers.google.com/android/work/overview)